# Get nextval sequence value by simple java Query on a PostgreSQL DB

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, hql

I'm working on a PostgreSQL Database and I am trying to recover a `nextval` sequence by a simple Query by Java, but It's not working :

```
  Query q = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT nextval(numcallcartnewcart) as num");
    BigDecimal result=(BigDecimal)q.getSingleResult();   
    return result.longValue();
```

(Of course it's not the best solution, but I can't do better, because I'm blocked by the Hibernate configuration with the composite-id tag which don't accept a generator sequence  like that :

```
        <column name="num_call" />
             <generator class="sequence">
                    <param name="sequence">numcallcartnewcart</param>
             </generator>
```

into the key-property tag :

```
   <key-property name="numCall" type="int">
    <column name="num_call"/>
   </key-property>
```

)
Here is the error of the Query:

```
 \-[METHOD_CALL] MethodNode: '('
    +-[METHOD_NAME] IdentNode: 'nextval' {originalText=nextval}
    \-[EXPR_LIST] SqlNode: 'exprList'
       \-[IDENT] IdentNode: 'numcallcartnewcart' {originalText=numcallcartnewcart}

    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.SelectClause.initializeExplicitSelectClause(SelectClause.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker.useSelectClause(HqlSqlWalker.java:845)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker.processQuery(HqlSqlWalker.java:633)
```

It's more or less the same with a createNativeQuery (but not the same error) :

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column « numcallcartnewcart » does not exist
  Position: 16
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2101)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1834)
```

EDIT : With quote

```
Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT nextval('numcallcartnewcart') as num");

        BigDecimal result=(BigDecimal)q.getSingleResult();   
        return result.longValue();
```

--

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERREUR: la relation « numcallcartnewcart » n'existe pas
  Position: 16
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2101)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1834)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255)
```

EDIT 2 : (The problem was that I don't have the sequence in my database (not in the good one...)

And we have to use a BigInteger, not a BigDecimal, and to use quote around sequence name :

```
    Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT nextval('numcallcartnewcart') as num");
    BigInteger result=(BigInteger)q.getSingleResult();   
    return result.longValue();
```

Comment: I think you do have to use createNativeQuery here unfortunately...just get it working in the SQL console then copy it to your java code :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The name of the sequence has to be passed as a string literal, not as an identifier:

```
entityManager.createQuery("SELECT nextval('numcallcartnewcart') as num");
```

More details in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-sequence.html

**Edit**

The error

> ERREUR: la relation « numcallcartnewcart » n'existe pas

indicates that no sequence with the name `numcallcartnewcart` exists. You need to create the sequence first.

Comment: No, it's not working, I've tried it before of course ^^.

Comment: @QuentinT.: The error message "*ERROR: column « numcallcartnewcart » does not exist*" is pretty clear. The cause of that is that you did not enclose the sequence name in **single** quotes. Do you *really* get that specific error message when put the sequence name in single quotes?

Comment: Yes the error message does not exist maybe, it's a translation from French by myself.

Comment: @QuentinT. "la relation" is "the relation" and that in turn means you do not have a sequence named `numcallcartnewcart`. Please show us your **exact** SQL code you used to create the sequence. Or the output of the `\ds` command in `psql`

Comment: Ok... It's a little shame for me... I had well the sequence in my database, but not in the good one... I had it in the production environment and I'm in test... So it couldn't work... Thanks a lot... It's work well with the sequence in the good DB... (just have to change a cast in BigInteger : see my edit2)