# Custom Hibernate Id Generator for 2 Hibernate Sessions

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I have a use case of dual write where I need to save entities to both Oracle and Postgres DB. I also want to implement a custom IdentifierGenerator to create new primary keys, which have to be consistent in Oracle and Postgres.

The entity is like below (Getter and Setter are ignored).

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@GenericGenerator(
    name = "CUSTOM_ID_GENERATOR",
    strategy = "<class reference>",
)
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( generator = "idGenerator")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
}
```

When saving the entity, what I'm gonna do is like:

```
User user = new User();
user.setName("USER_1");
long id = oracleSession.save(user);
user.setId(id);
postgresSession.save(user);
```

For my code, will it cause a new id to be generated in Postgres? If so, how should the implementation be to keep the same id in both Oracle and Postgres?

Is there a way to let the IdGenerator **NOT** generate a new value when the id is manually set?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`@GeneratedValue` will cause new value each time save method is called. So you don't have guarantee that the value would be same for `Oracle` and `PG`.
You need to use assigned Id in this case.

Your application should generate the id and should set to the user object. The assigned Id will then be saved to both the DB.
To do this you have to drop the `@GeneratedValue` annotation refer this [documentation page](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-simple-assigned).

Now the next question is how to generate unique Id for your tables, the simplest way is to use a sequence from either DB and get new value and set that to user object. Go through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29678640/3503187) for more information on this.